# Ubuntu 22.04 freezes after I suspend it a second time

Tags: 22.04, suspend, amd-graphics

I have ubuntu installed on a laptop with the next specifications:

- Hardware Model:HP HP Laptop 15-ef2xxx
- Processor: AMD® Ryzen 5 5500u with radeon graphics × 12
- Graphics: RENOIR (renoir, LLVM 15.0.6, DRM 3.47, 5.19.0-35-generic)
- GNOME version: 42.5
- Windowing system: Wayland

Recently, I've been experiencing the stated problem. It didn't used to happen in the past, so I guess it has something to do with recent updates. It specifically happens when I suspend the laptop a second time. If I do it only one time, it works normally. When it happens, the display stays black, and the only way to make it go back to normal is to force a shutdown.

The laptop has two activity lights. When it suspends normally,one of them blinks slowly. When it doesn't, however, it doesn't blink at all.

Comment: Can you look logs for errors ?

Comment: @IvanBazarnyi I did that and didn't find anything relevant. Although not an exact solution, I found out that by that by opening tty console (ctrl+alt+f1) and then switching back to tty2 (which is my default machine) showed the lock screen properly.

Comment: Have the same issue on my HP Elitebook 845 G9, AMD Ryzen 5 PRO 6650U, also on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, thanks for the tip with switching TTY, i had to restart until i knew that worked.

Comment: @EdR, did you find a proper solution finally? I have the same problem on HP Probook 455 G8 with 22.04 and AMD Ryzen 7 5800u (renoir, LLVM 15.0.7, DRM 3.47, 5.19.0-45-generic) and the workaround with tty switching does not help...

Comment: My brand new HP VIctus PC with AMD® Ryzen 5 5600g would not wake after suspending. The OS is 22.04 with Gnome 42.09 and Wayland. I installed the amdgpu packages and it seems fine now!

Answer (score 0):

This is what helped me finally! I'm giving the [link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-signed-hwe-5.19/+bug/2008774/comments/8) to the original post and fully quote it here for convinience:

> I was having this exact same problem on my HP Pavilion 14 on Ubuntu 22.04. It worked fine a few days ago but I encountered this problem after an update. Lots of stack answers pointed to some problems with Nvidia drivers, but I don't have Nvidia graphics. I have an integrated AMD Radeon along with AMD Ryzen 7.
>
> What worked for me:
>
> Installing `amdgpu-install` and installing the AMD graphic cards components[1] after checking the secure boot support[2]:
>
> ```
> amdgpu-install --usecase=graphics
> ```
>
> [1]https://amdgpu-install.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install-overview.html
>
> [2]https://amdgpu-install.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install-installing.html#ubuntu-and-debian-based-systems